# About $T^6$ and $T^2 \times T^2 \times T^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I read often that wen can see the six torus like  $T^2 \times T^2 \times T^2$. So, what is the difference between $T^6$ and $T^2 \times T^2 \times T^2$ ?

Comment: I mean, I guess they're not literally the same set. But they're diffeomorphic under an obvious/canonical diffeomorphism; the natural Riemannian structures on both are isometric; they have the same natural orientation; the same natural symplectic structure... There's no real difference whatsoever.

Comment: how do you define $T^6$

Comment: @Zakariae: Could you please add details on what structure(s) your tori come equipped with? For example, one often identifies $T^{2}$ and $S^{1} \times S^{1}$, which is fine up to diffeomorphism, but if you ask about Riemannian metrics (even flat metrics) "most" tori are not products of circles.

Comment: The difference between $T^6$ and $T^2 \times T^2 \times T^2$ is the same as the difference between an ordered 6-tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6)$ and the corresponding ordered 3-tuple of ordered 2-tuples $((a_1,a_2),(a_3,a_4),(a_5,a_6))$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thanks for clarifying this. I guess implicit in my statement above was that $T^6$ is the Clifford torus in $\Bbb C^4$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: By default, I'd assume $T^{n}$ means "modulo the integer lattice" (or "modulo $(2\pi\mathbf{Z})^{n}$"), in which case everything you said is perfectly correct. :) It just seemed prudent to get confirmation from the OP.